# How do I stop the SearchBar to open on my UITableView instead of over my entire view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on an App which main view consists of a MapView and a TableView, similar to the interface of the Foursquare-App. Now the problem I have is that when I hit the search bar of the App, the search window opens over the entire screen - but I'd only want it to open over the TableView.
Does any of you have an idea how to change the behaviour of the SearchBar so that it only laps over its "own" tableView and not the map view?

Here's the two images basicly describing the problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7vGU.png] //The view without search. The search should come up over the table view.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYTpE.png] // but it does not instead covers the whole map.

//Short edit: The map is actually a MapBox map, shouldn't change anything on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting question... I never tried something like this but I think that a possible way to do could be:

create a view controller with a searchDisplayController that I'll call SearchViewController

```
SearchViewController *searchVC = [[SearchViewController alloc] init]
```

and on the view controller that contain the map

```
[self addChildViewController:searchVC];

// assuming an Y offset of 200 pixel, but you can get the mapView height ... it's better
searchVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-200);

[self.view addSubview:searchVC.view];

if ([searchVC respondsToSelector:@selector(didMoveToParentViewController:)]) {

    [searchVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

This probably will not work perfectly but could a starting point... a I said I never tried, let me know if it  works

Comment: I really like the idea. I don't have the time to implement that thing now, since that would need some workaround (my UiView I've shown you already has a SearchDisplayController) but I'll keep you up-to-date as soon as I've tried it out. Thanks already!

Comment: I'm very sorry to disappoint you but I think is very hard to change the behavior of UISearchDisplayController without use private API, if I'll have time I'll try to implement the solution that I proposed you and I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

You add your search bar on view I think

you need to add search bar on HeaderView of table view

I think it will be work..

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Sadly, that's already how I'm doing it - which actually is the reason why it's so strange.